# How to pass the id to the sibling component from another sibling in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Below is my `app.routing.ts`

```
export const Approute: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'trip-details/:id',
        component: TripDetailsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'create-expense/:id',
        component: CreateExpenseComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'not-found', component : NotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found' }
 ];
```

`tripDetails.component.html`

```
 <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" [routerLink]="['../create-expense', tripId]"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> Create Expense</button>
```

Above i have 2 sibling components and am trying to navigate to another sibling component `CreateExpenseComponent` with `id, but am not able to navigate to`http://localhost:4200/home/create-expense`its redirecting me to`http://localhost:4200/not-found`.

Where am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud do the routing like this: `[routerLink]="['home', 'create-expense', tripId]`

Also, make sure that the tripId is defined in the current component.
You can get it like this (after injecting the route into the component's constructor):

```
 this.route
      .params
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.tripId = params['id'];
      });
```